# How to get only 1 input work instead of all input in for loop?

Tags: html, angular, mongoose

I'm working on an angular project and i have a form in for loop:

[image: 1]

Here's my angular html code:

```
<ul class="border">

        <li *ngFor="let cake of cakes; let idx = index">
          <img class="d-inline-block" src="{{cake.url}}" alt="{{cake.id}}" width="250" height="250">
          <form class="d-inline-block form-rate">
            <div class="form-group">
              <select name="stars" [(ngModel)]="newRate.stars" class="custom-select">
                <option selected value="1">1 stars</option>
                <option value="2">2 stars</option>
                <option value="3">3 stars</option>
                <option value="4">4 stars</option>
                <option value="5">5 stars</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea name="comment" [(ngModel)]="newRate.comment" class="form-control" id="rate-comment" rows="4"
                placeholder="Type your comment here"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group clearfix">
              <button class="btn btn-primary float-right btn-sm" (click)="ratingSubmit(cake._id)">Rate!</button>
            </div>

          </form>

        </li>

      </ul>
```

Whenever I type in textarea or select an value in that form it all do the same in that ul. How to fix this?

Here's my typescript file to show object and array in html.

```
export class RateSubmitComponent implements OnInit {
  cakes = [];
  cake = "";
  rates = [];
  rate = "";

  newCake: any;
  newRate: any;

  constructor(private _httpService: HttpService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCakesFromService();
    this.newCake = { name: "", url: "" };
  }

  getCakesFromService() {
    let observable = this._httpService.getCakes();
    observable.subscribe((data) => {
      this.cakes = data["data"];
    });
  }

  getRatesFromService() {
    let observable = this._httpService.getRates();
    observable.subscribe((data) => {
      this.rates = data["data"];
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    let observable = this._httpService.addCake(this.newCake);
    observable.subscribe((data) => {
      this.newCake = { name: "", url: "" };
      this.getCakesFromService();
    });
  }

  ratingSubmit(cakeId) {
    let observable = this._httpService.addRating(this.newRate, cakeId);
    observable.subscribe((data) => {});
    this.newRate = { stars: "", comment: "" };
    this.getRatesFromService();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

You are binding the different controls (within the for loop) which is causing this issue.

## Fix

You should create array of newRate with the same size of cakes and use the index `idx` for binding.

ts file

```
let newRates= []; //create the same size of cakes array.
```

html

```
        <li *ngFor="let cake of cakes; let idx = index">
          <img class="d-inline-block" src="{{cake.url}}" alt="{{cake.id}}" width="250" height="250">
          <form class="d-inline-block form-rate">
            <div class="form-group">
              <select name="stars" [(ngModel)]="newRates[idx].stars" class="custom-select">
                <option selected value="1">1 stars</option>
                <option value="2">2 stars</option>
                <option value="3">3 stars</option>
                <option value="4">4 stars</option>
                <option value="5">5 stars</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea name="comment" [(ngModel)]="newRates[idx].comment" class="form-control" id="rate-comment" rows="4"
                placeholder="Type your comment here"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group clearfix">
              <button class="btn btn-primary float-right btn-sm" (click)="ratingSubmit(cake._id)">Rate!</button>
            </div>

          </form>

        </li>

      </ul>
```

Comment: I just uplodade my ts file. Please take a look